# Celery with http as a transport layer

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, kombu

I want to use Celery as a task management framework, however my communication channel between the worker and the rabbitMQ broker must be over HTTP due network constraints. I know that RabbitMQ has a HTTP interface which is good enough for low rate usage, however I couldn't find a way for celery to use it.

Is there a way I can make kombu - Celery connection manager, use HTTP or replace it with another connection manager?

What is the proper way to solve such issue?